# Prism HTML highlighter

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, prism.js

I'm using [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) and its working well for CSS:

```
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

but i can't get it working for html:

```
<pre><code class="language-html"><p class="red">red text</p></code></pre>
```

I have 2 problems:

1. `<` and `>` are represented as tags, not as text, but i could replace it by `&lt;` and `&gt;`
2. More important, even replaced as shown in problem 1, the highliter will not highlight any code and everything is just black. Despite that it is working for CSS, whole code looks like this:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <link href="prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <script src="prism.js"></script>
>         <pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `<code class="language-markup">` to style html code.

Also, you only need to escape the beginning of the tags with `&lt;`, don't worry about the `&gt;` characters. The easiest way is to paste your html code into the pre tag, then perform a find and replace for all `<` characters.

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="prism.js"></script>
        <pre><code class="language-markup">
            &lt;p class="red">red text &lt;/p>
        </code></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aw man, all those html entities makes for some ugly source code...  Anyone know why Prismjs goes out of their way to remove html tags? Is it an option that can be set to true or false...

Comment: nm, saw [this](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/issues/572) conversation on Github... not a Prism thing, but is instead due to the <pre> tag...

Comment: Per my understanding <pre> tag supports embedded html tags. How is not prism issue?

Comment: Or you can put the code you want to highlight in a file, and have prism load and highlight it from the file and inject it into the page.

Comment: I serve regular HTML and break it with JavaScript.  Combined with a beautifier, it works quite well.  I find this particularly useful when I want to see both the code and a rendered example by cloning the example and place it into `<pre><code class="language-markup">` tags.

Comment: Another way to handle HTML syntax is to wrap your HTML code in `<script type="prism-html-markup"></script>` as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27495949/1097123. I think its much better than replacing `<` with `&lt;`

Answer (score 5):

I want to add that another very simple possibility is to use the archaic `<xmp>`-tag like so:

```html
<pre><code class="language-html">
<xmp>
  <p>this markup is now rendered as expected although your IDE might be upset about you using that old tag</p>
</xmp>
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

**To solve issue 1)**:

You can use the [unexcaped-markup plugin](http://prismjs.com/plugins/unescaped-markup/)

This is how it works:

```
<script type="text/plain" class="language-markup">
   <p>Example</p>
</script>
```

To ignore first and last returns I would recommend using the [normalize whitespace plugin](http://prismjs.com/plugins/normalize-whitespace/).

**To solve issue 2):**

There exists no `languages-html` see http://prismjs.com/index.html#languages-list. HTML is a HyperText**Markup**Language so its included in **language-markup**. Thats what you have to use.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the HTML. I didn't want to replace the <, > with &lt &gt so what I did was put the code inside textarea-elements inside a hidden div and once the page was loaded copied the contents of all textareas to code-elements. This way I was able to keep the code as it is and render it withou issues.

The obvious downside of course is that without JS there is no content but then again the highlighter wouldn't work either.

Comment: You don't have to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&rt;`. Just wrap your html code in `<script type="prism-html-markup"></script>`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27495949/1097123

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to save the html you want highlighted into a seperate file. You'll need to include the file highlight plugin into your js.

The syntax highlighting will be worked out from the extension

```
<pre data-src="assets/partials/picture.html"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Adam's answer should be the best solution in this case. I just elaborate more on the use for the [unexcaped-markup plugin](http://prismjs.com/plugins/unescaped-markup/) to make the HTML highlighter in the simplest way.

Since <script /> will only work on single line of code, therefore you may want to insert simple HTML-comment to escape all of your codes:

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code><!--
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
--></code></pre>
```

Everything inside the comment would be printed prettily. It's worth a try if you need to print you HTML markup by using [Prism](http://prismjs.com/).