# Prism.js syntax highighting not being applied

Tags: prism.js

I'm having an issue with Prism.js, where the highlighting is not being applied. I've included the prism.css and prism.js files, and an example of the code looks like this:

```
<pre class="line-numbers language-markup">
    <code>
        &lt;img src="example.png"&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

The code that displays on the front end however is all in black, with no syntax highlighting.

I'm also using Bootstrap if this has any effect.

Comment: The same exact question was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391425/markup-not-showing-up-using-prism-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markup Not Showing Up Using Prism JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391425/markup-not-showing-up-using-prism-js)