# How would I escape the opening < in a HTML opening tag

Tags: html, regex

I need a REGEX pattern that will transform a raw HTML block in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<anytag>
   <h1>This is the less than < symbol. </h1>
   <h1>This is the less than or equal to <= symbol. </h1>
</anytag>
```

Transforms to:

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html>
...
&lt;anytag>
   &lt;h1>This is the less than < symbol. &lt;/h1>
   &lt;h1>This is the less than or equal to <= symbol. &lt;/h1>
&lt;/anytag>
```

So that the < character in only HTML tags is replaced, and nowhere else.

This is to solve an issue with syntax highlighting of html with prism.js here:

[highlighting html with prism.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243726/highlighting-html-with-prism-js)

Thanks Washington Guedes

[image: Working]

Comment: just pseudo code, it should work on any html tag pattern

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. I don't see why you don't just HTML escape all entities.

Comment: because i'm trying to use prism.js to syntax highlight a raw block of html code and only the < on html tags needs to be encoded.  If i encode all of the entities then prism breaks. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I specifically need a regex pattern to do this.

Comment: In well-formed HTML, all left angle brackets which are not the start of a tag should already be encoded with entities.

Comment: "If i encode all of the entities then prism breaks." then file a bug report and use a better syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<(?![^>]*<)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/zB8kG3/1)

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score -2):

Here are some common entities. You do not need to use the full code - there are common aliases for frequently used entities. For example, you can use < and > to indicate less than and greater than symbols. & is ampersand, etc.

EDIT: That should be - &lt &gt and &amp