# Show HTML in WebView using Prism.js

Tags: java, javafx, webview, java-8, prism.js

I am having trouble showing `HTML` in `JavaFX`'s `WebVew` using `Prism.js`. I am able to successfully show a `Java` example, but the `HTML` example seems to want to show the HTML as it appears when you visit a site instead of just showing the syntax string. What is the correct way to display `HTML` in `JavaFX`'s `WebView` using `Prism.js`?

**Java Example (Displaying correctly)**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication319 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        String javaString = "/* HelloWorld.java\n"
                + " */\n"
                + "\n"
                + "public class HelloWorld\n"
                + "{\n"
                + " public static void main(String[] args) {\n"
                + "     System.out.println(\"Hello World!\");\n"
                + " }\n"
                + "}";

        String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "<head>"
                + "<link href=\"" + getClass().getResource("prism.css") + "\"" + " rel=\"stylesheet\"" + " type=\"text/css\"" + " />\n"
                + "<script src=\"" + getClass().getResource("prism.js") + "\"" + " type=\"text/javascript\"" + "></script>\n"
                + "</head>"
                + "<body>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<pre>"
                + " <code class=\"language-java\">\n"
                + javaString
                + "</code>\n"
                + "</pre>\n"
                + "</body>\n"
                + "</html>";

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.loadContent(htmlString);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

**HTML Example (Not displaying correctly)**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication319 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        String htmlStringPreCode = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "<head>\n"
                + "</head>\n"
                + "<body>\n"
                + "This is a Test\n"
                + "</body>\n"
                + "</html>\n";

        String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "<head>"
                + "<link href=\"" + getClass().getResource("prism.css") + "\"" + " rel=\"stylesheet\"" + " type=\"text/css\"" + " />\n"
                + "<script src=\"" + getClass().getResource("prism.js") + "\"" + " type=\"text/javascript\"" + "></script>\n"
                + "</head>"
                + "<body>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<pre>"
                + " <code class=\"language-html\">\n"
                + htmlStringPreCode
                + "</code>\n"
                + "</pre>\n"
                + "</body>\n"
                + "</html>";

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.loadContent(htmlString);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

**Java: 1.8.0_171**

**Prism.js Download in the picture has Java selected also**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html code needs to be escaped first (so it can be displayed as a plain text).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243726/highlighting-html-with-prism-js), both solutions work:

```
htmlStringPreCode = htmlStringPreCode.replace("<", "&lt;");

//or

htmlStringPreCode = "<script type=\"prism-html-markup\">" + htmlStringPreCode + "</script>";
```